# Acid-base extraction lab exercise

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I have a solid mixture of trans-cinnamic acid and menthol. I’m new to this organic chemistry business and I don’t know if I can react the acid directly out of the solid mixture with a basic solution or if I need to dissolve them both into a nonpolar solvent first. Probably a dumb question but thanks anyway

Comment: Sodium cinnamate is moderately soluble in water and menthol only slightly soluble so I think you could separate them without a second solvent. Much easier to use a second solvent such as ethyl acetate or diethyl ether though

Comment: If the grains of the two were mixed you might be able to dissolve one and leave the other. However if the two compounds coat each other then you might need to dissolve both to get a good separation.